# Grid System Doesn't Style Correctly in VFP Components - Vertical Alignment

Tags: visualforce, lightning, visualforce-component, lightning-design-system

Using Lightning Design System in a VFP, displayed on a lightning page through a VFP component, the grid system doesn't appear to be working on vertical alignment.

What am I missing?

### Code:

```
<apex:page showHeader="false" standardStylesheets="false" sidebar="false" applyHtmlTag="false" applyBodyTag="false" docType="html-5.0">
    
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
            <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
            <title>SLDS ResponsiveDesign Visualforce Page in Salesforce Mobile</title>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
            
            <!-- Import the Design System style sheet -->
            <apex:slds />
        </head>
        <body>
            
            <!-- REQUIRED SLDS WRAPPER -->
            <div class="slds-scope">
                
                <!-- PRIMARY CONTENT WRAPPER -->
                
                <!-- RESPONSIVE GRID EXAMPLE -->
                <div class="myapp">
                    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center">
                        <div class="slds-col">
                            <span>1</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col">
                            <span>2</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="slds-col">
                            <span>3</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
</html>           
</apex:page>
```

### Render:

[image]

### Update:

Adding visual height to the grid div is close:

```
<div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center" style="height:90vh">
```

100vh resulted in a scroll bar, I'm assuming vh is taking the overall size of the VFP lightning component as opposed just the visualforce page content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected: your columns are vertically centered in your grid. What I think you want to achieve is to center the columns on the page. In this case, I suggest you expand your grid to fit the page. One way could be to use vh units in the outer div and a relative height in the inner ones.

Example

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>SLDS ResponsiveDesign Visualforce Page in Salesforce Mobile</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

    <!-- Import the Design System style sheet -->
    <apex:slds />
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- REQUIRED SLDS WRAPPER -->
    <div class="slds-scope" style="height:100vh">

      <!-- PRIMARY CONTENT WRAPPER -->

      <!-- RESPONSIVE GRID EXAMPLE -->
      <div class="myapp" style="height:100%">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical-align-center" style="height:100%">
          <div class="slds-col">
            <span>1</span>
          </div>
          <div class="slds-col">
            <span>2</span>
          </div>
          <div class="slds-col">
            <span>3</span>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```